# How to show the string value instead of blank fields

Tags: crystal-reports

using Crystal Report 7

I want to display '-' instead of 0, i created a formula like this

```
if {pay_latecomededuct.upto15d} = 0 then
  '-'
else
  {pay_latecomededuct.upto15d}
```

the above formula is showing error as "A string is required here"

If i change the numeric instead of '-', not showing any error, even i tried with totext / tonumber also, result is same...

How to solve this problem.

Need Crystal report help

Comment: You're formula is not allow to return two data types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You formula needs to return a consistent value.  In this situation, that would be a string.

Add the following to the field's Display String formula:

```
If {pay_latecomededuct.upto15d} = 0 Then
  '-'
Else
  ToText({pay_latecomededuct.upto15d})
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather try formatting the field.

Right Click and choose `Format Field`

On The `Number` Tab click `Customize`

In the `Custom Styles` Window, click the `Number Tab`

Look for the option `Show Zero Value as` and change it from `Default Format` to `-`